# PHP error until print

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following code:

```
$period = new DatePeriod(
new DateTime($interval['start']),
new DateInterval('P1D'), 
new DateTime($interval['end']) 
);
$date_ob_array = iterator_to_array($period);

foreach ($date_ob_array as $date_ob) {
//print_r( $date_ob );
    print_r( $date_ob->date );
}
```

My problem; until `print_r( $date_ob )` is commented i get warning on first element: `Undefined property: DateTime::$date` next elements is ok; if this line is uncommented everything goes ok. I tried `reset($date_ob_array)`, but this didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `var_dump($date_ob)` show on the first element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$date_ob->date
```

use:

```
$date_ob->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

to return date in proper format. Both `DateInterval` and `DateTime` contain this method.